# How to Display output from MYSQL Full-Text query in PHP using Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, full-text-search

i read this post but i really don't understand it..
[Retrieving matched context of MySQL fulltext search in PHP (and security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188440/retrieveing-matched-context-of-mysql-fulltext-search-in-php-and-security)

How can i display data from MYSQL Full-Text query in PHP using Foreach..
When i try to do it, only 1 row is retrieve in fact, when i try to use MYSQL workbench it outputs 2 rows..

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $s = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);
    $search = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE MATCH (docu_title,description) AGAINST (:s)");
    $search->bindParam(':s', $s);
    $search->execute();
    $find = $search->rowCount();
    $search->fetch();
    if ($find == 0) {
        $searching =  0;
     }
     else{
        $searching = 1;
     } 
}
```

my PHP code

```
<?php
                    if (isset($searching)) {
                        if ($searching != 0) {
                            foreach($search as $sss)
                            {
                                echo "<td>" . $sss['docu_title'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $sss['description'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='downloads?id=" . $sss['id'] . "'>download</a></td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

please help me with this..
i'm still newbie.
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each $search->fetch(), you are fetching one row and the cursor moves to the next one, hence everytime the second row is being populated in the table. So, remove the $search->fetch() in the first code, and it will display all the rows.

Comment: thank you.. i already removed the $search->fetch() and it's working :)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `$find = $search->rowCount();`rubbish.

Also use `while()`to loop through all the returned records instead of `foreach()`. To use `foreach()` you need to use [**fetchAll()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which returns all the records instead of `fetch()`which only returns 1.

```
$search = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE MATCH (docu_title,description) AGAINST (:s)");
$search->bindParam(':s', $s);
$search->execute();
while($sss =$search->fetch());
{
    echo "<td>" . $sss['docu_title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $sss['description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='downloads?id=" . $sss['id'] . "'>download</a></td>";
}
```